# run a transaction in a map Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have values in a map say like below.

```
Stats:{
     population: 5,
     }
```

Is there a way to run a transaction to the `population` field.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, use dot notation to update a field in a map, https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects. Which language are you using? Do you have a snippet of an example transaction you're trying to run?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database and the code that you are using to run the transaction.